# Unable to access Outlook mail on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, email, javascript, windows-live

Immediately after logging in to Outlook mail, I get a tool-tip about "Focused and Other inboxes". After clicking on the 'Got It' button, I am unable to open anything. Everything on the page is disabled and there's a rectangular box that keeps flashing around the "Focused" and "Other" menus. I have attached a few screenshots of this issue. How can I get rid of this?

[image: Image showing got it button]

Comment: Open the page with no add-ons or extensions active (you can use incognito mode for this) and see if it still happens.

Comment: @StevenDavison Just tried it in incognito window. It's still the same.

Comment: sorry to be picky, are any addons/extensions active in your incognito mode?

Comment: @StevenDavison No I manually disabled all the extensions in incognito and then checked it.

Comment: Can you try on another browser?

Comment: @StevenDavison I tried it on Firefox where I dont have any add-ons or extensions installed. It still doesnt work.

Comment: I have clicked everywhere on the page, nothing works on any browser.

Comment: All on the same machine?

Comment: @StevenDavison All on the same machine running Windows 8.1 I dont have another PC to check but I can try it on Ubuntu.

Comment: it's not logical it would be a machine issue (unless something is affecting all browsers), but it's possible. try on Ubuntu.

Comment: @StevenDavison Hey, it works well on Ubuntu, browser Google Chrome.

Comment: I am using the same set of extensions on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: I suspect something on the windows machine that is causing this, but not knowing your machine, can't offer an answer. I'd suggest updating and doing full scans with AV and AntiMalware tools and ensuring OS and Applications are fully updated

Comment: @StevenDavison Ok I'l try doing that when I get some time and post updates here. Meanwhile I have disabled the "Focused Inbox" from the options menu in Outlook Mail. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments :-

Log on with another machine, and disable the Focused Inbox.

Log on to affected machine, and the prompt should be gone.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem -- the Tool Tip totally hijacked my Hotmail! I resolved it by going to the Deleted folder as soon as the Inbox came up and opened a message before the tool tip could load. That prevented it from loading and I was able to disable Focused Inbox from the Options menu as you mentioned.